# Tomcat 7.0 starting up fine, but not testing

Tags: tomcat7

I installed Tomcat 7.0 on my Windows 7 machine. It seems to be running properly:
it gets started on Eclipse. Following is the entire log on Console:

```
Jun 30, 2013 10:16:25 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin;C:\windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:/Program Files/Java/jre7/bin/client;C:/Program Files/Java/jre7/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre7/lib/i386;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem;C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\bin; C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin; c:\Borland\Bcc55\bin; C:\MinGW\bin; C:\MinGW\MSYS\1.0\local\bin; C:\MinGW\MSYS\1.0\bin; C:\MinGW\MSYS\1.0;  C:\MSYS\1.0; C:\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.6.2\include\c++\bits; C:\MinGW\MSYS\1.0\home\boost\boost_1_51_0; c:\Users\AYSE\apache-tomcat-7.0.40\bin; c:\Users\AYSE\apache-tomcat-7.0.40; c:\Users\AYSE\apache-tomcat-7.0.40\lib; ;C:\Users\AYSE\Downloads\eclipse;;.
Jun 30, 2013 10:16:28 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jun 30, 2013 10:16:28 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jun 30, 2013 10:16:28 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 4825 ms
Jun 30, 2013 10:16:28 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Jun 30, 2013 10:16:28 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.12
Jun 30, 2013 10:16:30 PM org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGenerator createSecureRandom
INFO: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [290] milliseconds.
Jun 30, 2013 10:16:30 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jun 30, 2013 10:16:30 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jun 30, 2013 10:16:30 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 1993 ms
```

It is starting up properly on Windows as well.

However, when I try to open the URL

```
http://localhost:8080/
```

in the browser, I receive an HTTP 404 error message that the requested source is not available.

I followed the instructions on http://www.coreservlets.com/Apache-Tomcat-Tutorial/tomcat-7-with-eclipse.html to install it. I also tried the port 80 as in the default setup.

It is running to execute the basic servlets.

What am I missing ???

//==============================================================================

UPDATE:

I since change the server location on Eclipse from

```
"Use workspace metadata (does not modify Tomcat installation)"
```

to

```
"Use Tomcat installation (takes control of Tomcat installation)".
```

This time, when I attempt to start Tomcat from Eclipse, I am receiving the following error message in a pop-up window:

```
Server apache-tomcat-7.0.40 at localhost was unable to start within 45 seconds. If the server requires more time, try increasing the timeout in the server editor.
```

and the log on Eclipse Console is

```
Jun 30, 2013 10:46:00 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: 

<... the contents of my PATH environment variable...>
```

However,

The bin folder of Tomcat unzipped files is in PATH. Not just that, I've also added the basic Tomcat folder and the \lib folder into the path.

//==============================================================================

UPDATE: restarted Eclipse and worked !

still don't have much idea what went wrong there.

will use "with care" for a while i guess.